# My webpage is 2 column but overlaps into 1 column when zoomed in?

Tags: html, css

I am so frustrated: whenever I zoomout on this webpage, everything gets messed up. How do I center the web page so that I can zoomout and the elements don't get positioned badly. (its supposed to be 2 columns but everything conjoins into 1) I have tried `<center>` but that doesnt work for some reason.

[www.officialnewvintage.com/joel.html](http://www.officialnewvintage.com/joel.html)

Comment: best is that you strictly give each one width:% or px in order you don't want to get messed up when it zoom in out

Answer (score 0):

Do not use center tag. Its outdated and not effective. I would set an id to `margin: 0 auto;`

A basic example is shown on this site: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/centering-a-website/